# Вывести все чаты и .юзеров и только часть сообщений

Tags: java, база-данных, spring-data-jpa

Не понимаю, как одним запросом достать все чаты с участниками и их сообщения, но не все, а часть (например, 20). Это же неправильно - доставать все сообщения, или я ошибаюсь? Мой код:

```
public class Chat {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @JsonView(Views.Id.class)
  private Long id;

  @JsonView(Views.Id.class )
  @ManyToMany
  private List<User> members;

  @JsonView(Views.Id.class)
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "chat", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Message> messages;
}

public class Message  implements Serializable {   
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "message", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Content content;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
  private User author;

  private Chat chat;
}
```

и

```
User
```

Есть запрос

```
@Repository
public interface ChatRepo extends JpaRepository<Chat, Long> {
   List<Chat> findChatsByMembersContains(User user);
}
```

в котором я получаю все чаты залогиненного usera с его участием и все их сообщения. А мне нужна только часть сообщений (limit 20).

Вопрос в том, как получить все чаты авторизованного пользователя с его участием и только часть сообщений (20) ???

Это список чатов, в котором есть список пользователей и список части сообщений (20), возможно ли это и что нужно сделать.

Нужно ли для этого создавать базу данных другим способом, или есть очень хитрый запрос, который я не нашел, или вырезал лист, когда вытащил его? Я думаю, что последнее не является хорошим вариантом или, возможно, нужна другая логика

прошу на вопросы которые я не задавал не писать ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Написать такой запрос через find точно не получится.

В чем принципиальность получить все данные одним запросом? Список каких сущностей на выходе вы хотите получить? В репозитории можно написать любой запрос через аннотацию @Query, можно использовать JPA и нативные запросы, например:

```
@Query("select...", nativeQuery = true)
List<Сущность> findBy...(...)
```

Подробнее можно посмотеть здесь https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Думаю, что само решение тянуть все сразу неправильно. Логично показывать список чатов, а сообщения загружать по мере необходимости, там можете загрузить список 20 последних сообщений для конкретного чата. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result

```
 List<Message> findTop20ByChat(Chat chat);
```